# Change the input-boxes background to gradient

Tags: html, css

I've tried this CSS, but none of them was working:

```
.login_field{
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #5189E9 0%, #2453A3 100%);
}
```

HTML

```
<input class="login_field" id="username">
<input class="login_field" id="password" type="password">
```

I'm trying to make the input-boxes look like this:
[image: example]

Comment: Well your code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I would not normally recommend this just add `!important` to your CSS.

```css
.login_field {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #5189E9 0%, #2453A3 100%) !important;
}
```

```html
<input class="login_field" id="username">
<input class="login_field" id="password" type="password">
```